# Call localhost api with url rewrite

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-web-api2

I have an WebApi and an angular site.
The angular part is on an public address.
Is it possible to reach the api without exposing it?

I was thinking that maybe it could be done using url rewrite (I'm a newbie with url rewrite) but so far I have had no luck.

For example if the site has the address somesite.com and call somesite.com/api/cars to retrieve a list of cars. Then the rewrite should change it ti localhost:5000/api/cars.

Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by not exposing it ? The API has to be public for your app to get to it.

Comment: I was hoping I could get to it with rewrite rules so I didn't have to have it public.

Comment: The nature of JavaScript gives you no opportunity to hide such, and why do you want to hide that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible. I don't know what I was thinking.
Since Angular is on the client you can't access the server if you call localhost. Localhost will only call the computer you have the browser installed on.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to deploy a static server such as NGINX / Apache to deliver angular files and further use it as reverse proxy to fetch data from your API, then yes, you can rewrite your URL as `localhost:5000/api/cars`.

You may further configure your server running on port 5000 to only accept requests from `localhost / 127.0.0.1`. Hence `somesite.com:5000/api/cars` would not be accessible from the outer world.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this just with URL Rewrite alone, you will have to install [ARR](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing). When you have that installed you can put in a rule like this to achieve what you want:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Reverse Proxy to api" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^api/cars/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5000/api/cars/{R:1}" />
    </rule>        
</rules>
```